# How do I change the int variable in a cycle and if so is there a more efficient way?

Tags: c++, variables, switch-statement, cycle

First post ever on this site so spare my life , please.
I'm trying to do a little encryption and decryption program imitating the Enigma cipher/machine from the WW2 (enough history lessons)

So I'm trying to input a number and a letter like so : 1h 2e 3l 4l 5o ;
Because I don't use a cycle I need to write for every variable that I'm adding the number , but what do I do if I have less letters than variables?The only way I can think of is using a cycle which checks if the input is a letter or not.That's why the current code I've written only can be used for specific amount of numbers and  letters...

```
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>
using namespace std;
int main()
{

int opt;
cout<<"Enter 1 for encryption and 2 for decryption. "<<endl;
cin>>opt;
if(opt == 1)
  {
  int setting1,setting2,setting3,setting4;
  char a,b,c,d;
  cout<<"_________________________________________________"<<endl;
  cin>>setting1>>a>>setting2>>b>>setting3>>c>>setting4>>d;
    a+=setting1;
    b+=setting2;
    c+=setting3;
    d+=setting4;
  cout<<(char)a<<" "<<(char)b<<" "<<(char)c<<" "<<(char)d<<endl;

  }
if(opt == 2)
  {
  int setting1,setting2,setting3,setting4;
  char a,b,c,d;
  cout<<"_________________________________________________"<<endl;
  cin>>setting1>>a>>setting2>>b>>setting3>>c>>setting4>>d;
    a-=setting1;
    b-=setting2;
    c-=setting3;
    d-=setting4;
  cout<<(char)a<<(char)b<<(char)c<<(char)d<<endl;

  }
  if(opt !=1 && opt !=2)cout<<"ERROR!"<<endl;



  std::cout << "Press ENTER to continue..."<<endl;
  std::cin.ignore( std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(),'\n');
  return 0;
}
```

Also I was told that the last 2 lines would prevent the .exec from closing after it's done doing it's thing.

Comment: First off, spearing you may end your life.  Secondly, your questions are regarding the requirements, which we were not given.  Review your requirements with the Originator of the requirements.

Comment: Why don't you use loops or *cycles*?  This looks like a good purpose for a loop because if one of the input operations fail, you don't know which operation failed.

Comment: Oh my bad about the whole spearing thing...My mother language isn't English so I guess I have made a typo there.Also thank you for the help!

Comment: what's the point of the cast in `(char)a`? `a` is already a char

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend inputting your data in loops (cycles).  But before that is accomplished, I suggest using a structure (or class) with an overloaded stream extraction operator.

```
struct Number_Letter
{
  int number;
  char letter;
  friend std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& inp, Number_Letter& nl);
};
std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& inp, Number_Letter& nl)
{
  inp >> nl.number;
  if (inp)
  {
    inp >> nl.letter;
    if (!isalpha(nl.letter))
    {
      // Error recovery for not reading a letter
    }
  }
  else
  {
    // Error recovery for failing to read number.
  }
  return inp;
}
```

Your input loop would be something like:

```
Number_Letter nl;
while (std::cin >> nl)
{
  // process the data
}
```

For cryptography, you may want to keep the data as a string:

```
std::string message;
getline(cin, message);
for (unsigned int i = 0; i < message.length(); i += 2)
{
  if (!isdigit(message[i]))
  {
    cerr << "Invalid message type at position " << i << endl;
    break;
  }
  if (i + 1 > message.length())
  {
    cerr << "Missing letter at end of message.\n";
    break;
  }
  if (!isalpha(message[i+1]))
  {
    cerr << "Invalid message type at position " << i << endl;
    break;
  }
}
```

Comment: How will this compile? `inp >> number;` ? 
And you don't need `friend` with struct

Comment: Corrected the overloaded `operator>>` to input into member variables.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're trying to check for an unknown sequence of character/integers and need a loop to do the check?

```
int opt;
cout<<"Enter 1 for encryption and 2 for decryption. "<<endl;
cin>>opt;

if(opt != 1 && opt != 2)
{
  cout << "Error" << endl;
  return -1;
}

int integer;
char character;
char again;

do
{
    cout<<"_________________________________________________"<<endl;    

    cin>>integer>>character;

    if(opt == 1) {
        character+=integer;
    } else if(opt == 2) {
        character-=integer;
    }

    cout << character <<endl;

    cout << "Again (Y)?: ";
    cin>>again;
}while(again == 'Y' || again == 'y');

std::cout << "Press ENTER to continue..."<<endl;
std::cin.ignore( std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(),'\n');
return 0;
```